# Using file browser to get text file and read it by JAVA

Tags: java, file, browser, text

I am new in Java.
I need to determine the text file's location using the file browser and then read its content using Java.
So, how could I doing so?
Thanks so much,
Regards,
Aya.

Comment: What file browser are you talking about? The latter can be found via google!

Comment: Are you searching for file handling/ read-write code? Check first few google search results for *Java file handling*. Try those, and ask any problem that come along.

Comment: are you programming some desktop user interface and looking for the open-file widget ? (something like in a Menuebar File > open... / something that behaves like the shortcut Ctrl+O) ??

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest that you start with a tutorial such as this:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html

Once you have selected the file you want to read, you need to read it. There are lots of ways to do this in Java. My favorite approach is to use a library. I'd suggest Google Guava. Using that library you can write this:

```
List<String> fileContents = Files.readLines(File file, Charsets.UTF8);
```

I hope this helps.